# SQL Order of precendence of query expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to work out how SQL queries are run and have hit a bit of a stumbling block.

If a where clause akin to the below is used:

A OR B AND C

This could mean either of the below

(A OR B) AND C

***or***

A OR (B AND C)

In the majority of cases the results will be the same, but if the set to be queried contains solely {A}, the first variant would return an empty result set and the second would return {A}. SQL does in fact return the 1 result.

Does anyone know (or have links to) any insight that will help me understand how queries are built?

Ketchup

Comment: Can't provide any links, but I believe they are left associative.  In other words, (A OR B) AND C.  For the sanity of other programmers (and yourself), please, always use parenthesis in this situation.

Comment: Thank you corbin, if i was writing it i would, but we are creating a search function for our intranet that allows the user to perform search terms using "AND" "OR" and "ANDNOT" operators, and am trying to work out how it should be coded

Comment: @Corbin: That is not correct. `AND` has higher precedence than `OR` in SQL (not only in SQL-Server but in all SQL dialects)

Comment: @ypercube Interesting. Never seen a language before where they are not equal precedence.  Good to know.

Comment: @Corbin: I think it's the same in C but I could be wrong there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is the following according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx):

> 1. ~ (Bitwise NOT)
> 2. (*) (Multiply), / (Division), % (Modulo)
> 3. (+) (Positive), - (Negative), + (Add), (+ Concatenate), - (Subtract), & (Bitwise AND), ^ (Bitwise Exclusive OR), | (Bitwise OR)
> 4. =, >, <, >=, <=, <>, !=, !>, !< (Comparison operators)
> 5. NOT
> 6. AND
> 7. ALL, ANY, BETWEEN, IN, LIKE, OR, SOME
> 8. = (Assignment)

Comment: Thank you Panayiotis, i think my googling failed me not being able to find that.

Answer (score 2):

In the knowledge (from documentation) that `AND` has a higer precedence than `OR`, you should aim to write predicates for `WHERE` clauses in  conjunctive normal form ("a seires of `AND` clauses").

If the intention is

```
( A OR B ) AND C
```

then write it thus and all is good.

However, if the intention is

```
A OR ( B AND C )
```

then I suggest you apply the [distributive rewrite law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting) that results in conjunctive normal form i.e.

```
( P AND Q ) OR R   <=>  ( P OR R ) AND ( Q OR R )
```

In your case:

```
A OR ( B AND C ) <=>  ( A OR B ) AND ( A OR C )
```

Answer (score 0):

`AND` and `OR` have different precedende.

See [Precedence Level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For SQL-Server (which is your tag) here is the precedence http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx but..
If you're worried about the exact result set given you should indeed start working with () subsets.